# Node : Excel to buffer conversion loses styling

Tags: node.js, xlsx, excel4node

I have a scenario where Im using the 'excel4node' npm dependency to create a excel workbook with some custom styling in it (Like block lettered headers etc). I'm converting it to buffer using `wb.writeToBuffer()` in excel4node library, and writing it to an s3 bucket. On the other end, I'm fetching the object from the s3 bucket, and converting the buffer from s3 back to excel file using the XLSX dependency (Cuz looks like excel4node doesnt support buffer to excel conversion) as follows

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

let workbook = XLSX.read(data.Body);
const wbout = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer'});
```

In this conversion process, I am losing the custom styling I added while creating the excel file using excel4node dependency. How do I handle this case where I dont want to lose the custom styling.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861696/js-xlsx-preserve-cell-style-while-writing-to-xlsx-file?rq=1) help you?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, yes it did retain the styling. Thanks for the comment